# How to write emoticons in python CSV?

Tags: python, excel

I make a parser and upload the data to excel. The problem arose with uploading data to Excel. In the text itself there are emoticons that he turns into something strange. How to fix it? Or exсel does not support emoticons?

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    for off in data:
        line = [off.title, off.text, off.image_link,
                off.categ, off.city]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Is your question about Python or about Excel? Your title implies the problem is Python writing the CSV, your text implies the problem is Excel reading the CSV. Did you verify with another program?

Comment: By default Excel does not use UTF-8 encoding to open the CSV format. Given that your output routine works correct, you can work around that by using Excel's text import assistant https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0